# Prevent "submit" of inline edit AG-Grid

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I'm working on an inline-editable table using Ag-Grid (v 17.0), the problem is that  whenever I finish the edition of a row and hit enter, the change is "committed", the behavior I would like to have is to keep the user in "edit-mode" until the request to the backend retrieves a success response.

I have looked over and over into Ag-grid documentation, played with a lot of different events (cellValueChanged, rowValueChanged, editingStopped, etc.) to no avail.

I would like to keep the ag-grid code *if possible*, meaning I don't want to fork their code and change this inside their component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone comes here looking for the answer.. I managed to do what I wanted not disabling the "submit", but checking the inputs on the `onRowChanged()` event and then if any errors existed setting the focus to the cell that had something wrong. `gridApi.setFocusedCell( cellIdentifier )`.

This happens so quickly the user can't difference between both scenarios.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know the library but that comes from either one of this :

- You surrounded your inputs with a form
- The enter keystroke is bound to the input.

First case, remove the form.

Second case, override the enter keystroke with this on your input :

```
<input type="text" (keyup.enter)="null">
```

Comment: All that input/form logic is abstracted inside ag-grid, I have tried stopping the propagation of `(keydown.enter)` with no luck at all